# Error in Parsing dblp.xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to parse whole dblp.xml file and store all records in database system in order to use in my project. So I am using XmlDocument  class from System.XML in C#. I have written following piece of code

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("output.xml");
XmlNodeList articles = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/article");
XmlNodeList phdthesis = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/phdthesis");
XmlNodeList inproceedings = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/inproceedings");
XmlNodeList proceedings = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/proceedings");
XmlNodeList www = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/www");
XmlNodeList books = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/book");
XmlNodeList incollection = xdoc.SelectNodes("dblp/incollection");
```

When line 2 xdoc.Load("output.xml") executes, Following error occurs.

**Reference to undeclared entity 'uuml' on line 25, position 38**

Kindly help me to handle this error and what is meant by this error. dblp.xml file is used in many projects. whether this is error in xml format or error due to code. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with your XML file? I think you should try to decrease the XML validation level. Is it this file? http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.xml

Comment: Yes I have downloaded file from dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.xml.gz. and How to decrease validation level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, as the exception displays - the referenced entities are not found. The entities defined in the dblp.xml can be found in the dtd file "dblp.dtd". [You can find that here.](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.dtd)

The easiest way to go is to fix the DOCTYPE. The current one in the XML file is not valid, you should have it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd" [
<!ENTITY % extern SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
%extern;
]>
```

This tells the parser that there is an external file containing the definitions. I have just tested this solution and runs fine.

Or you could just simply copy the Entity definitons from the dblp.dtd to your xml file. This way defining them, so they can be referenced later in your XML file.

I made the following file, that can be loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp [
    <!ENTITY Agrave  "&#192;" ><!-- capital A, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY Aacute  "&#193;" ><!-- capital A, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY Acirc   "&#194;" ><!-- capital A, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY Atilde  "&#195;" ><!-- capital A, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY Auml    "&#196;" ><!-- capital A, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY Aring   "&#197;" ><!-- capital A, ring -->
    <!ENTITY AElig   "&#198;" ><!-- capital AE diphthong (ligature) -->
    <!ENTITY Ccedil  "&#199;" ><!-- capital C, cedilla -->
    <!ENTITY Egrave  "&#200;" ><!-- capital E, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY Eacute  "&#201;" ><!-- capital E, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY Ecirc   "&#202;" ><!-- capital E, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY Euml    "&#203;" ><!-- capital E, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY Igrave  "&#204;" ><!-- capital I, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY Iacute  "&#205;" ><!-- capital I, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY Icirc   "&#206;" ><!-- capital I, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY Iuml    "&#207;" ><!-- capital I, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY ETH     "&#208;" ><!-- capital Eth, Icelandic -->
    <!ENTITY Ntilde  "&#209;" ><!-- capital N, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY Ograve  "&#210;" ><!-- capital O, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY Oacute  "&#211;" ><!-- capital O, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY Ocirc   "&#212;" ><!-- capital O, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY Otilde  "&#213;" ><!-- capital O, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY Ouml    "&#214;" ><!-- capital O, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY Oslash  "&#216;" ><!-- capital O, slash -->
    <!ENTITY Ugrave  "&#217;" ><!-- capital U, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY Uacute  "&#218;" ><!-- capital U, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY Ucirc   "&#219;" ><!-- capital U, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY Uuml    "&#220;" ><!-- capital U, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY Yacute  "&#221;" ><!-- capital Y, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY THORN   "&#222;" ><!-- capital THORN, Icelandic -->
    <!ENTITY szlig   "&#223;" ><!-- small sharp s, German (sz ligature) -->
    <!ENTITY agrave  "&#224;" ><!-- small a, grave accent -->   
    <!ENTITY aacute  "&#225;" ><!-- small a, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY acirc   "&#226;" ><!-- small a, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY atilde  "&#227;" ><!-- small a, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY auml    "&#228;" ><!-- small a, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY aring   "&#229;" ><!-- small a, ring -->
    <!ENTITY aelig   "&#230;" ><!-- small ae diphthong (ligature) -->
    <!ENTITY ccedil  "&#231;" ><!-- small c, cedilla -->
    <!ENTITY egrave  "&#232;" ><!-- small e, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY eacute  "&#233;" ><!-- small e, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY ecirc   "&#234;" ><!-- small e, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY euml    "&#235;" ><!-- small e, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY igrave  "&#236;" ><!-- small i, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY iacute  "&#237;" ><!-- small i, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY icirc   "&#238;" ><!-- small i, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY iuml    "&#239;" ><!-- small i, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY eth     "&#240;" ><!-- small eth, Icelandic -->
    <!ENTITY ntilde  "&#241;" ><!-- small n, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY ograve  "&#242;" ><!-- small o, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY oacute  "&#243;" ><!-- small o, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY ocirc   "&#244;" ><!-- small o, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY otilde  "&#245;" ><!-- small o, tilde -->
    <!ENTITY ouml    "&#246;" ><!-- small o, dieresis or umlaut mark -->

    <!ENTITY oslash  "&#248;" ><!-- small o, slash -->
    <!ENTITY ugrave  "&#249;" ><!-- small u, grave accent -->
    <!ENTITY uacute  "&#250;" ><!-- small u, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY ucirc   "&#251;" ><!-- small u, circumflex accent -->
    <!ENTITY uuml    "&#252;" ><!-- small u, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
    <!ENTITY yacute  "&#253;" ><!-- small y, acute accent -->
    <!ENTITY thorn   "&#254;" ><!-- small thorn, Icelandic -->
    <!ENTITY yuml    "&#255;" ><!-- small y, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
]>


<dblp>
<article mdate="2002-01-03" key="persons/Codd71a">
<author>E. F. Codd</author>
<title>Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model.</title>
<journal>IBM Research Report, San Jose, California</journal>
<volume>RJ909</volume>
<month>August</month>
<year>1971</year>
<cdrom>ibmTR/rj909.pdf</cdrom>
<ee>db/labs/ibm/RJ909.html</ee>
</article>

<article mdate="2002-01-03" key="persons/Hall74">
<author>Patrick A. V. Hall</author>
<title>Common Subexpression Identification in General Algebraic Systems.</title>
<journal>Technical Rep. UKSC 0060, IBM United Kingdom Scientific Centre</journal>
<month>November</month>
<year>1974</year>
</article>

<article mdate="2002-01-03" key="persons/Tresch96">
<author>Markus Tresch</author>
<title>Principles of Distributed Object Database Languages.</title>
<journal>technical Report 248, ETH Z&uuml;rich, Dept. of Computer Science</journal>
<month>July</month>
<year>1996</year>
</article>
</dblp>
```

I used the following C# code to load the XML file:

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlReaderSettings setting = new XmlReaderSettings();
            setting.CheckCharacters = false;
            setting.ProhibitDtd = false;
            setting.CheckCharacters = false;
            setting.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;

            var reader = XmlTextReader.Create("E:\\text.xml", setting);
            doc.Load(reader);
```

I've just tested and the umlauts in "Zürich" are getting loaded right this way too.

You can add the entity definition to the original big XML file too, this way enabling the usage of entities with XmlDocument.

Alternatively you could preprocess the XML file to replace the problematic character sequences, what could be done using XSLT or simle file processing (read the XML file as a text file and replace the problematic strings).

However it is possible to use XmlDocument to process this huge XML file, I think it is highly disadvantageous. It consumes hell a lot os memory. You could be using XmlReader to read the needed values, or may XmlPathReader if you want to stick to XPath expressions.

Comment: It is the only example for ENTITY list, thanks very much!